# Using goroutines to process values and gather results into a slice

Tags: go, slice, goroutine

I'm recently exploring Go and how goroutines work confuse me.

I tried to port code I had written before into Go using goroutines but got a `fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!` error.

What I'm trying to do is use goroutines to process items in a list, then gather the processed values into a new list. But I'm having problems in the "gathering" part.

Code:

```
sampleChan := make(chan sample)
var wg sync.WaitGroup

// Read from contents list
for i, line := range contents {
    wg.Add(1)
    // Process each item with a goroutine and send output to sampleChan
    go newSample(line, *replicatePtr, *timePtr, sampleChan, &wg)
}
wg.Wait()

// Read from sampleChan and put into a slice
var sampleList []sample
for s := range sampleChan {
    sampleList = append(sampleList, s)
}
close(sampleChan)
```

What's the right way to gather results from goroutines?

I know slices are not threadsafe so I can't have each goroutine just append to the slice.

Comment: How is `newSample` implemented?

Comment: @kennytm check the answer I have explained the answer with an exmple similar to your use case

Comment: @kennytm newSample reads a string, chops it up, makes type conversions to int, float64... and sends a new struct `sample` to the channel

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your code is almost correct. There's a couple of problems: first, you're waiting for all the workers to finish before collecting the results, and second your `for` loop terminates when the channel is closed, but the channel is closed only after the `for` loop terminates.

You can fix the code by asynchronously closing the channel when the workers are finished:

```
for i, line := range contents {
    wg.Add(1)
    // Process each item with a goroutine and send output to sampleChan
    go newSample(line, *replicatePtr, *timePtr, sampleChan, &wg)
}

go func() {
    wg.Wait()
    close(sampleChan)
}()

for s := range sampleChan {
  ..
}
```

As a note of style (and following https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#synchronous-functions), it'd be preferable if `newSample` was a simple, synchronous function that didn't take the waitgroup and channel, and simply generated its result. Then the worker code would look like:

```
for i, line := range contents {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(line string) {
        defer wg.Done()
        sampleChan <- newSample(line, *replicatePtr, *timePtr)
    }(line)
}
```

This keeps your concurrency primitives all together, which apart from simplifiying `newSample` and making it easier to test, it allows you to see what's going on with the concurrency, and visually check that `wg.Done()` is always called. And if you want to refactor the code to for example use a fixed number of workers, then your changes will all be local.

Comment: Thanks. So the deadlock happens because the `Wait()` was not asynchronous, and not because the channel was unbuffered? I'm just trying to wrap my head around this so that I can make use of concurrency better

Comment: Making the channel large enough also works, although it uses extra storage for the channel.

Comment: Also just to clarify, how does `for s := range sampleChan` still work even when after `Wait()` is triggered? I though that closing an unbuffered channel will flush its contents with it. Thanks for the help

Comment: `close()` is like a special sort of write to the channel -- it doesn't flush the contents.

Comment: @PaulHankin I didn't know that about `close`ing a channel. Thanks for the tidbit!

Answer (score 7):

There are two problems

1. **Using unbuffered channels**: Unbuffered channels block receivers until data is available on the channel and senders until a receiver is available.That caused the error
2. **Not closing the channel before range**: As you never close the ch channel, the range loop will never finish.

You have to use a `buffered` channel and `close` the channel before range

**Code**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func double(line int, ch chan int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    ch <- line * 2

}

func main() {
    contents := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    sampleChan := make(chan int,len(contents))
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    // Read from contents list
    for _, line := range contents {
        wg.Add(1)
        go double(line, sampleChan, &wg)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    close(sampleChan)
    // Read from sampleChan and put into a slice
    var sampleList []int

    for s := range sampleChan {
        sampleList = append(sampleList, s)
    }

    fmt.Println(sampleList)
}
```

Play link : https://play.golang.org/p/k03vt3hd3P

**EDIT**: 
Another approach for better performance would be to run `producer` and `consumer` at  concurrently

**Modified code**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func doubleLines(lines []int, wg *sync.WaitGroup, sampleChan chan int) {
    defer wg.Done()

    defer close(sampleChan)
    var w sync.WaitGroup
    for _, line := range lines {
        w.Add(1)
        go double(&w, line, sampleChan)
    }
    w.Wait()
}

func double(wg *sync.WaitGroup, line int, ch chan int) {
    defer wg.Done()
    ch <- line * 2
}

func collectResult(wg *sync.WaitGroup, channel chan int, sampleList *[]int) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for s := range channel {
        *sampleList = append(*sampleList, s)
    }

}

func main() {
    contents := []int{0,1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19}
    sampleChan := make(chan int, 1)
    var sampleList []int

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    wg.Add(1)
    go doubleLines(contents, &wg, sampleChan)
    wg.Add(1)
    go collectResult(&wg, sampleChan, &sampleList)
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println(sampleList)
}
```

play link: https://play.golang.org/p/VAe7Qll3iVM

Comment: Thanks. This works for my case. But what if the length of the original slice is huge, will there be a problem in creating a huge buffer?

Comment: You can create channels with upto `2147483647` buffer size. But I would rather run the consumer  function parallelly with the producers if possible

Comment: Hi, I just tried your last example (the one with collectResult function) in playground,
It seems it is failing the collect the double of last element 19. 
I am kind of beginner and still trying to understand things, example seems good to my eyes, If you can explain why it is failing ( or not failing ) , that would be great. Thanks !

Comment: @knpercinel thanks for noticing It was because the main was not waiting for `collectResult` to process everything